# Inotifywait not getting executed after one execution

Tags: linux, shell, inotify

I have a shell script and within which i am using 'inotifywait' to monitor three directories. As soon as file comes within directory 'dirToProcess' some processing is done and then files get moved to either 'successDir' or 'failedDir' directory.

Now as soon as any files gets moved or copied in any of the directory I want inotifywait to get executed.

Here is the code i am executing:

```
inotifywait $dirToProcess $successDir $failedDir -e create -e moved_to --   
   exclude "\.(swx|swp|end|en1)" |
 while read path action file; do
    if [ -f $dirToProcess/$file ]; then
            doSomething;
    elif [ -f $successDir/$file ]; then
            cleanDir $successDir        # function which has some specific logic
            exit 0;
    elif [ -f $failedDir/$file ]; then
            cleanDir $failedDir         # function which has some specific logic
            exit 0;
    else
            c4lx_log "File $file not in poll, archive or failed, then why did we get notified?"
            exit 0;
    fi
```

Here is the problem:
As soon as files comes in 'dirToProcess' inotifywait notice it and gets called. But after processing when files are getting moved to '$successDir' or '$failedDir' ( by same code which processed files within 'dirToProcess' inotifywait does not get executed. But if i am moving files manually in either of those two dir everything seems to be working fine.

Can someone give me some pointer here or explain if i am missing any details here.

( i tried using -m or -r option with inotifywait but does not seems to be working )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `-m` flag for `inotifywait` to continue execution after the first event.

Comment: as i said i did but even with -m it seem to be working sometime and sometime not.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Without `-m` it will absolutely not work. With `-m`, you may have some other problem to diagnose.

Comment: all code does is call some other function which process files within directory dirToProcess  and the  moves file to either 'successDir' or 'failedDir'. I am not sure how that can be a problem

Comment: does order of where -m is use matters ?